# What to do? Yslow reports Empty src and href

Tags: javascript, performance, joomla, href, src

So I tested my site on GTmetrix, and yslow is detecting 2 js empty `src` or `href`.  It detects most of the time, a few time it's not detected.

my website is www.homelifepartners.com, it is using joomla CMS.

My problem is, I can't seem to find the 2 instances in javascript.
I searched the following in chrome inspect element:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "";
```

but 0 found.  Is it possble the attribute can appear in different variations?
If so, please give me some visual examples, as I am not really a programmer nor expert coder.

Comment: var img = new Image(); and img.src = ""; searched separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 `script` tags with empty `src`, in this case it's not actually empty, it's pointing to root index "/" which is also considered empty hence considered performance penalty. On Chrome, go to www.homelifepartners.com, view the source code (command+alt+u on Mac) then search for `src="/"`, you'll find the 2 instances where it occurs.
I'm no Joomla expert but try to find which plugin (or sort of) is including these tags and fix it asap.